# Use IOS app to wirelessly send key commands to Mac/PC

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, keyboard, wireless

I am looking into developing an IOS app that sends key commands to a Mac wirelessly.

To do this I am trying to find a way of using an iPhone/iPad as a bluetooth keyboard for the Mac. When a button on the screen of the phone/tablet is pressed, it would send a user assigned set of keystrokes (for example "Command + Shift + A + B") to the Mac.

These keystrokes would then run a keyboard shortcut that the user had already set up in the running application on the Mac (exactly as if the user had pressed "Command + Shift + A + B" on the actual keyboard).

Does anyone know how I would have to go about setting up this bluetooth connection? If any other wireless connection type would be more suitable, which also does not require the installation of software on the Mac please feel free to suggest them also.

Thanks!

(For the admins - I am new to this site, if I need to rephrase this question please let me know, don't just reject it!)

Comment: An iOS app cannot act as a HID (ie keyboard) device. You will need a companion app on the Mac to receive information from the iOS device either via Bluetooth or wifi and enter the right keystones.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would not be able to emulate a bluetooth keyboard? The top answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080464/how-to-send-a-message-from-iphone-to-mac-pc) made it seem like simulating a keystroke was possible, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: That post just talks about connecting an app on the device connecting to an app on a pic or Mac. An iOS app can't implement HID or HID over GATT profiles.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your help. Do you happen to know if this kind of app would be achievable on an Android device?